# How to include list of jar in different apk with various versions in Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My task is to have dailyDebug, dailyRelease, standardDebug and standardRelease apk files as a result of gradle build. Each apk should contain list of common applications with different versions and types e.g dailyDebug should contain jar1 with latest.integration version and with type: debug and the standardRelease with version 01.05.02 and type: release.

In build.gradle I have the following build types:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig null
        }
        debugDaily {
            signingConfig null
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig null
        }
        releaseDaily {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig null
        }
}
```

Here is the jar list that should be included in each apk.

```
 "jar1:latest.integration:release"
 "jar2:latest.integration:release"
 "jar3:latest.integration:release"
 "jar4:latest.integration:release"
 "jar5:latest.integration:release"
```

One of the simplest solution is to have a lot of copy-pastes like this:

```
dependencies {
    debugApk "jar1:01.02:debug"
    debugApk "jar2:02.03:debug"
    debugApk "jar3:05.12:debug"
    debugApk "jar4:01.32:debug"
    debugApk "jar5:02.01:debug"

    releaseApk "jar1:01.02:release"
    releaseApk "jar2:02.03:release"
    releaseApk "jar3:05.12:release"
    releaseApk "jar4:01.32:release"
    releaseApk "jar5:02.01:release"

    debugDailyApk "jar1:latest.integration:debug"
    debugDailyApk "jar2:latest.integration:debug"
    debugDailyApk "jar3:latest.integration:debug"
    debugDailyApk "jar4:latest.integration:debug"
    debugDailyApk "jar5:latest.integration:debug"

    releaseDailyApk "jar1:latest.integration:release"
    releaseDailyApk "jar2:latest.integration:release"
    releaseDailyApk "jar3:latest.integration:release"
    releaseDailyApk "jar4:latest.integration:release"
    releaseDailyApk "jar5:latest.integration:release"
}
```

I am looking for a generic solution, because the list of jars is going  to be larger and larger and in the future it will be very hard to maintain.

Thank you in advance, it's the first post here :)

Comment: Are you looking for this https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2

Comment: I know about flavors, but I can't use it. Thanks

Comment: Try to do it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share it with you.
So 2 functions are added in build.gradle:

```
def getDailyPackages(type){
         String[] packages = [
                    "jar1:latest.integration:${type}"
                    "jar2:latest.integration:${type}"
                    "jar3:latest.integration:${type}"
                    "jar4:latest.integration:${type}"
                    "jar5:latest.integration:${type}"]
            return packages
        }

def getStandardPackages(type) {
        String[] packages = [
                "jar1:${jar1VersionName}:${type}",
                "jar2:${jar2VersionName}:${type}",
                "jar3:${jar3VersionName}:${type}",
                "jar2:${jar4VersionName}:${type}",
                "jar3:${jar5VersionName}:${type}",]
        return packages
    }
```

Jar version names are declared in ext section:

```
ext {
    jar1VersionName = '1.02'
    jar2VersionName = '1.03'
    jar3VersionName = '1.04'
    jar4VersionName = '1.05'
    jar5VersionName = '1.06'
}
```

And finally call them with corresponding types:

```
dependencies {
    debugApk(getStandardPackages("debug"))
    releaseApk(getStandardPackages("release"))
    debugDailyApk(getDailyPackages("debug"))
    releaseDailyApk(getDailyPackages("release"))
}
```

I hope this post was helpful :)